# How can my lost phone disappear from my Android device manager device list?

Tags: lost-phone

I lost one of my phone 2 months ago. I've sometimes checked Android device manager to locate it and try locking it, but recently my lost phone disappears from the list ! How it can happen ? Does a person know the way to skip this link in order to use or to sell the lost phone ? I still have the original box of this phone (with its IMEI).
Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When the playstore is logged in from a new account,your previous account will notify that the device is removed from the playstore device list. so it will not show your old phone.

Comment: Is there any way to identify the new "owner"?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the new "owner" factory-resets the device, it no longer has a Google account associated – and thus the link to ADM dies. Same if the account is removed from the device: Google services no longer have a way to query the device using your account information, as the device won't recognize those anymore.

There are also other possibilities:

- battery is empty, so the device died.
- battery was removed
- dedive went into airplane mode
- device was placed on a train track, and a train passed on top of it
- device was drowned in the sea and short-circuited

Many more possibilities, but I better stop here – you've got the idea ;)

Comment: All other possibilities, possibly not the a case of removal of account, not even humorously